# If $X\in\mathscr L^5$, then $X\in\mathscr L^1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a random variable $ X $. Im suppossed to prove or disprove if $ X \in {\mathscr L}^5 $, then $ X \in {\mathscr L}^1$.
However, I dont know what $\mathscr L $ is suppossed to mean. I dont have the script for the course so I dont know how it was defined. However, I know that Lebesgue integration was covered in the course if thats helpful.
Edit:
As sugessted in the comments, I tried using the Hölder inequality, where I get something like this:$$E(|X^2|) \ \le \ E(|X|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \ E(|X|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}} $$
I tried $p=2$ and $p=5$ in hopes of getting rid of the $E(|X^2|)$ or trying to sneak the 5th power of $X$ in, but it didnt work. For $p=2$, $$
E(|X^2|) \ \le \ E(|X|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ E(|X|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=E(|X|^2)
$$ I get a very trivial result and for $p=5$, I get the following:
$$
E(|X^2|) \ \le \ E(|X|^5)^{\frac{1}{5}} \ E(|X|^{\frac{5}{4}})^{\frac{4}{5}}
$$
And from here I intended to show that $E(X^5) \le E(X^2) \lt \infty$
but I cant rearrange the equation in that way.

Comment: It means that $\Bbb E[|X|^5]$ is finite.

Comment: If $E |X|^{5} < \infty$ does it follow that $E |X| < \infty$?

Comment: @FShrike do You know if the statement is true or false ?

Comment: it is true${}{}{}$ *for probability spaces*

Comment: Do you know basic properties of the expectation? Do you know Hölder's inequality?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes I know both. Ive tried to use it but with no avail

Comment: @FShrike how do You know?

Comment: Think about it? Can you get any **simple** inequalities relating $|X|^5$ with $|X|$? When do these hold?

Comment: @100xln2 This isn't a "do my homework for me" site.  You have been given some hints in the comments, and the expectation is that you would use those to make an attempt at the problem and specify where you get stuck.

Comment: @user6247850 yes I know. I have edited the question now to include it, no worries :)

Comment: Can you use Hölder's inequality so that  $\mathbb{E}(\vert X\vert)$ is on the LHS and $\mathbb{E}(\vert X\vert^5)$ appears in the RHS?

Comment: The title and first paragraph are a different question from the rest of your post and the answers.  Which are you trying to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative proof of the Ljapunov inequality mentioned in the other answer is to use Holder's inequality to show $$\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \mathbb{E}[1\cdot |X|] \le \mathbb{E}[1^p]^{1/p} \cdot \mathbb{E}[|X|^q]^{1/q} = \mathbb{E}[|X|^q]^{1/q}.$$  Now, choosing $q = 5$ gives $$\mathbb{E}[|X|] \le \mathbb{E}[|X|^5]^{1/5} < \infty.$$

Comment: Oh, that is neat!

Comment: thank you! Completely forgot that one randomvariable can be a constant.

Answer (score 3):

For $0<s<t$ it holds that $\left(E|X|^{s}\right )^{1/s} \leqslant \left (E|X|^{t}\right )^{1/t}$ (the Ljapunov inequality). This is a consequence of monotone convergence and the [Jensen inequality](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_5_jensen%27s_inequality.php). Conclude that
$$E|X| \leqslant \left (E|X|^{5}\right)^{1/5}<\infty. $$

---

Proof of Ljapunov. Define $Y_n(\omega) := (\min \{|X(\omega)|,n\})^s$, hence $EY_n \leqslant n^s$ is finite. The map $h(x) :=|x|^{t/s}$ is convex, so by Jensen
$$ (EY_n)^{t/s} = h(EY_n) \leqslant Eh(Y_n) = E(Y_n)^{t/s} = E(\min \{|X|,n\}^t) \leqslant E|X|^t. $$
Since $Y_n\nearrow |X|^s$ we have $EY_n \nearrow E|X|^s$ by monotone convergence. It follows that $(EY_n)^{t/s}\nearrow \left(E|X|^s\right )^{t/s} \leqslant E|X|^t$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way.

$$\int |X|\,dP = \int_{|X|<1}|X|\,dP+\int_{|X|\geq 1}|X|\,dP \leq 1+E |X|^{1+\epsilon}<\infty,\quad \epsilon>0 $$